# PASCAL string to array

Tags: arrays, string, pascal

How can I convert a string of numbers like for example `'21354561321535613'` into digits and store them in an array?

Each digit should be turned into an integer element in the array, so the string `'21354561321535613'` should result in:

```
[2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1, 5, 3, 5, 6, 1, 3]
```

Comment: [StrToInt](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/strtoint.html) and [For-in](http://wiki.freepascal.org/for-in_loop)

Comment: Should each digit be turned into an element in the array?

Comment: yes,each digit be turned into an element in the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily turn a digit into an integer by subtracting the ordinal value of `'0'`. Do this in a loop and you have an integer for each digit:

```
var
  S: string;
  A: array of Integer;
  I, Len: Integer;
begin
  S := '21354561321535613';
  Len := Length(S);

  { Reserve Len Integers. }
  SetLength(A, Len);

  { Convert each digit into an integer: }
  for I := 1 to Len do
    A[I - 1] := Ord(S[I]) - Ord('0'); { [I - 1] because array is zero-based. }
end;
```

Comment: can i ask another question please,why when i use a function from a unit, and this function contains an array, the array will be one-based ?

Comment: **If you want to ask another question, then, well, ask another question**. Anyway, in Pascal, static arrays (e.g. `array[7..12] of Integer`) can have any base (in this case, `7`). The index can be any ordinal, so even Char or Boolean or an enumerated type. Dynamic arrays (e.g. `array of Integer` if declared as var or type) are always zero-based and the index is always an integer. The `A` in my answer is such a dynamic array, and is thus always zero-based.

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and read the documentation you have for your dialect of Pascal very carefully. For Delphi, that is the Delphi (or Object Pascal) Language Guide and is part of the help that comes with it. For FreePascal, you can find something like it online. For other Pascals, you'll have to find it yourself.

Comment: I got it!, it's very helpful. then i will take my chance and ask, is there a type bigger then int64 in pascal ? (because i had to calculate 100! to use it in a problem).

Comment: There is no built-in integer type that is larger than UInt64. If you need something bigger, try my [BigInteger implementation](https://github.com/rvelthuis/BigNumbers). It can handle 100! and even 1000! easily.

Comment: FWIW, you could at least upvote and/or accept my answer.

Comment: i did approve your answer, and i've alredy downloaded this implementation and i didn't know how to use it

Comment: Take a look at the test code for BigInteger. It shows how to use them.

Comment: hi, i've been reading the test and i really dont get it, should call it as a unit in my program or as a type ? and the result will be a string or a number ?
i'm using free pascal

Comment: You *use* the unit `Velthuis.BigIntegers.pas` (as `Velthuis.BigIntegers`) and then you can do something like this complete little program: `program useBigInt; {$APPTYPE CONSOLE} uses Velthuis.BigIntegers; var n: BigInteger; begin n := '1234567890123456789'; n := n * 77777; Writeln(string(n)); Readln; end.` I can't type newlines in comments, but I guess you get where they should be.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, explain, please, what is the fundamental difference between your answer and my answer given earlier?

Comment: I don't use IntToStr. And I explain a little more.

Comment: i tried to compile it as u said but it shows this error :
Fatal: You need ObjFpc (-S2) or Delphi (-Sd) mode to compile this module

Comment: Then use one of these with the given options. AFAIK, ObjFpc is free, while Delphi certainly isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  Str: string;
  Arr: array of Integer;
  i: Integer;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Str := '21354561321535613';
  Len := Length(Str);
  SetLength(arr, Len);

  for i := 1 to Len do
    Arr[i - 1] := StrToInt(Str[i]);  
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to covert String to Array of bytes)

```
uses crt;
var
        s:string;
        a:array[1..1000] of byte;
        i:byte;
begin
        s:='1234567';
        for i:=1 to length(s) do
                val(s[i],a[i]);
end.
```

Answer (score -1):

it sample to convert numbers as string to numbers use the function

```
 strtoint(number_in_string);
```

to convert numbers to numbers as string  use the function

```
inttostr(number);
```

Comment: That's not what is being asked for. They want to have an array of _digits_, not a single integer.