# Pascal module compiling error

Tags: compilation, freepascal

while compiling in FreePascal 3.0.0 it shows this error : Fatal: You need ObjFpc (-S2) or Delphi (-Sd) mode to compile this module.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is then probably for a Delphi like mode, while the default is a Turbo Pascal mode. Set one of the selected parameters, or use {$mode to do it in source. See the [FPC manual e.g. this topic](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.0.0/user/userse33.html) for details for both the concept of compiler modes and the parameters and directives

Comment: I assume (due to an almost identical comment in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41229224/95954)) that he is trying to compile my [BigInteger](http://www.rvelthuis.de/programs/bigintegers.html) unit. If that is the case, he'll probably need Delphi, although perhaps ObjFpc can compile it as well. My code was designed for Delphi. I never tried it with FreePascal.

Comment: That won't compile at all, even in delphi mode, since it uses units with namespaces and Delphi versioning (compilerversion>2) without any wrapping or abstraction, and the FPC RTL hasn't been renamed to namespace notation

Comment: OK, thanks for the heads up. He could rename the units (remove the `Velthuis.` part) and try again, but it uses operators, record methods, lots of assembler, etc. I doubt that this will compile, as-is, with FreePascal.

Comment: It is not the use of namespaces in /your/ unit names, but the assumption that the RTL/VCL units are in that format, so basically the same as the difference of XE2+ and (even unicode versions) before.. E.g. in the implementation part of randomnumbers.there is a reference to "system.sysutils". As always, FPC has features from the very latest versions, but also misses features from even very old versions (e.g. dynamic packages related, and some win3->win95 migrational things)

Comment: Yes, I got that a little later. But he could also rename those. But I agree that it is very unlikely it will compile with FreePascal.

Comment: operators, generics, record methods and in trunk even XE7 features as gettypekind work and trunk has an initial implementation of generics.* too. The first thing to fix would be to centralize all conditional checks in the beginning of the units in an .inc file.

Comment: Hmmm... then he should try to rename the units (my units and the RTL units used) and recompile. I will try this myself. Would be interesting to see if I can make it compile. If so, I will try to publish an FCP-compatible version of the units as well. I've got some time next week.

Comment: If it works then, i hope u post a link in here, thanks.